# Git merge - Three way 'git merge'

Tags: git, merge

I am trying to simulate the example on three-way merge process in `git` given [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging), Below is the figure provided explaining three-way merge.
[image: Figure 1: Three way merge in Git]
To understand this, I have created a file `testfile` under my git project directory and made changes as below:

**Commit C0**

```
echo 'Commit #0 - master branch' >> testfile
git add testfile
git commit -m 'commit 0'
```

**Commit C1**

```
echo 'Commit #1 - master branch' >> testfile
git commit -a -m 'commit 1'
```

**Commit C2**

```
echo 'Commit #2 - master branch' >> testfile
git commit -a -m 'commit 2'
```

**Commit C3**

```
git checkout -b iss53
echo 'Commit #3 - iss53 branch' >> testfile
git commit -a -m 'commit 3'
```

**Commit C4**

```
git checkout master
echo 'Commit #4 - master branch' >> testfile
git commit -a -m 'commit 4'
```

**Commit C5**

```
git checkout iss53
echo 'Commit #5 - iss53 branch' >> testfile
git commit -a -m 'commit 5'
```

Now, in order to merge changes from both the branches, as shown in below image, I executed `git merge` command.

[image: Figure 2: Merge]

**Merge**

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge iss53
```

**Merge Result**

```
Auto-merging testfile
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in testfile
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

$ cat testfile
Commit #0 - master branch
Commit #1 - master branch
Commit #2 - master branch
<<<<<<< HEAD
Commit #4 - master branch
=======
Commit #3 - iss53 branch
Commit #5 - iss53 branch
>>>>>>> iss53
```

**My questions**

1. Why doesn't it merge the file contents from both the branches to `testfile` (so that `testfile` contains 5 lines from 5 commits)?
2. How to change this example such that three-way merge can be studied, avoiding the merge conflict? (Any other case can be mentioned wherein three-way merge occurs successfully, without any merge conflict error)

I have also tried with `git rebase`, but merge conflict error is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the same line on the same file, Git cannot be sure how to properly resolve the conflict. Adding lines at the same spot is the same case.

Change your sequence from

```
echo 'Commit #0 - master branch' >> testfile
git add testfile
git commit -m 'commit 0'
echo 'Commit #1 - master branch' >> testfile
git commit -a -m 'commit 1'
echo 'Commit #2 - master branch' >> testfile
git commit -a -m 'commit 2'
git checkout -b iss53
echo 'Commit #3 - iss53 branch' >> testfile
git commit -a -m 'commit 3'
git checkout master
echo 'Commit #4 - master branch' >> testfile
git commit -a -m 'commit 4'
git checkout iss53
echo 'Commit #5 - iss53 branch' >> testfile
git commit -a -m 'commit 5'
git checkout master
git merge iss53
```

to

```
echo 'Commit #0 - master branch' >> testfile
git add testfile
git commit -m 'commit 0'
echo 'Commit #1 - master branch' >> testfile
git commit -a -m 'commit 1'
echo 'Commit #2 - master branch' >> testfile
git commit -a -m 'commit 2'
git checkout -b iss53
echo 'Commit #3 - iss53 branch' > testfile.new
cat testfile >> testfile.new
mv testfile.new testfile
git commit -a -m 'commit 3'
git checkout master
echo 'Commit #4 - master branch' >> testfile
git commit -a -m 'commit 4'
git checkout iss53
echo 'Commit #5 - iss53 branch' > testfile.new
cat testfile >> testfile.new
mv testfile.new testfile
git commit -a -m 'commit 5'
git checkout master
git merge iss53
```

and you will get a successfull automatic three-way-merge.